# R ggbreak have non-transparent background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a plot with `ggbreak`; however, it seems that the background is no longer transparent even if I adapt the theme to have panel and background be transparent. Is there a way around this?

Minimum working example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

set.seed(2022-08-23)
d <- data.frame(x = 1:20,
   y = c(rnorm(5) + 4, rnorm(5) + 20, rnorm(5) + 5, rnorm(5) + 22))
 
plt1 <- ggplot(d, aes(y, x)) + geom_col(orientation="y") + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), 
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",  colour = NA)
  )

ggsave(plt1, filename = "test1.png", device = 'png', bg = 'transparent')

plt2 <- ggplot(d, aes(y, x)) + geom_col(orientation="y") + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), 
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",  colour = NA)
  ) + scale_x_break(c(7, 17), scales = 1.5)
ggsave(plt2, filename = "test2.png", device = 'png', bg = 'transparent')
```

the file `test1.png` is indeed with a transparen background, but not `test2.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `ggbreak` works via `ggplotify`. What this means is that the existing plot is actually built into a grob table of 2 or more panels and this complex grob tree is used as an annotation layer of a new ggplot object. Unfortunately, this means the resulting object breaks the normal expectations of ggplot. En route, it picks up solid backgrounds which are opaque `rectGrob` objects.

This means that there may be no easy way to get a transparent background with `ggbreak`. It *is* possible to make the background transparent, but it requires a bit of grob-hacking:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

set.seed(2022-08-23)
d <- data.frame(x = 1:20,
   y = c(rnorm(5) + 4, rnorm(5) + 20, rnorm(5) + 5, rnorm(5) + 22))


plt2 <- ggplot(d, aes(y, x)) + geom_col(orientation="y") + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), 
          plot.background = element_blank()
  ) + scale_x_break(c(7, 17), scales = 1.5)

plt3 <- ggplotify::as.ggplot(grid::grid.draw(plt2, recording = FALSE))

grobs <- plt3$layers[[2]]$geom_params$grob 
grobs$grobs[[1]] <- zeroGrob()
groblets <- grobs$grobs[[6]]$children
groblets[[1]] <- zeroGrob()
groblets[[4]]$grobs[[37]] <- zeroGrob()
groblets -> grobs$grobs[[6]]$children
grobs -> plt3$layers[[2]]$geom_params$grob 

ggsave(plt3, filename = "test2.png", device = 'png', bg = 'transparent')
```

Here is the result overlaid on text in a word processor:

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I found a different work-around (that I put in the next answer) but this one shows how to navigate within a grob object, which is very useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `ggbreak` is using the default theme while re-building the plot with breaks. So a work-around is to make the default theme transparant:

```
# modify the default theme 
old_theme <- theme_get()
theme_update(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), 
        plot.background = element_blank()
)

plt3 <- ggplot(d, aes(y, x)) + geom_col(orientation="y") + scale_x_break(c(7, 17), scales = 1.5)
ggsave(plt3, filename = "test3.png",  device = 'png', bg = 'transparent')

# restore the theme
theme_set(old_theme )
```

Comment: Very nice. I think this is a better approach than mine.